# Handling monthly occurances with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a website where people record (or log) the distance of their runs. I want to create a leader board that will automatically reset to zero after the month is over. If I could save their total distance for that month as well, that would be ideal. Every run is tied to IDs and I have a variable that adds up the monthly distance, but obviously when they log a new run that changes. I don't know how I would make it record this month only and not freak out if they log in advance.

Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried making a monthly distance value for MySQL so each time they log, if it is that month, it will add to it. But how should I make it reset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're tracking the date of each run, right? Then you should be able to do something like this and avoid having to store the totals:

```
SELECT SUM(Runs.Miles) as MonthlyTotal
FROM Runs
where MONTH(Runs.Date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) and YEAR(Runs.Date) = YEAR(CURDATE())
```

(Presumably you'd also filter by or group by the UserID. Also, I suspect it may be more efficient to pre-calculate the beginning and end of the month and use `BETWEEN` in the where clause. Consult our friend `EXPLAIN`.)

If your read load is too high to make this practical, you could store the monthly total in a different table and update it with a trigger every time a run is added or updated, and via cron at the start of every month. This kind of de-normalization always makes things more complicated, so I avoid it until I have reason to believe it's necessary.